# real-time mysql insert query using c

Tags: mysql, c, raspberry-pi, real-time, remote-access

Good Day,

I am trying to learn on how to save my data in MySQL database using C in real-time.

I am using a Raspberry Pi MCU, and an external web server where the data will be saved. I am also using C to get the data from the sensors and would like to save it to my external database, but I do not know how to proceed with this problem as I am not that familiar with using C and MySQL together. though my main concern here is how do i make sure that my data is real-time, or when my sensors get the data it will then be saved to the database.

I'm thinking of doing an infinite loop inside my main and will place an if statement that will serve as a trigger whenever there is a data from the sensors and will save it to the mysql server.

but i am not sure if that is the most efficient way of doing this, that is why if you have any better ideas of how to retrieve my data in real-time using C and saving it to MySQL then it would be greatly appreciated.

in PHP i would have simply made a cron job for this but since i will be doing this in C, I am at lost on how to proceed or if my idea is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at two independent problem:

1. Retrieve the data at a fixed interval
2. Save the data to a database.

For the first, there are two known methods, the first is polling which means stay in a while loop and constantly check if updates are available. The second method is using interrupts, you should choose the most appropriate for your problem but for beginning you can use the first method and when the program works (maybe) move it to interrupts.

For the second, just install MySQL and mysql C connector, just go to their site and download and install it. Its connection is pretty simple and there are a lot of examples online, both for combining and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to do such things is called 'the hardware interrupt'. You should read the docs to check if the hardware supports it.